# Different variables for release vs staging versions of Ionic 2 RC1

Tags: cordova, angular, mobile, webpack, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 RC1 and trying to have a dynamic API endpoint.  I can detect if Cordova is present and use localhost if it is not.  However, I'd also like for my test builds to hit a staging.domain.com endpoint, while release builds via `ionic build --release android -prod` hit www.domain.com.

Is this possible?

```
if(this.platform.is("cordova")){
  // if release build hit http://www.domain.com
  // else hit http://staging.domain.com
}else{
  this.root = "http://localhost:3000";
}
```

I noticed the new RC1 has /src/app/main.prod.ts and /src/app/main.dev.ts, but I'm not sure how to use those...